# Sphinx search stopwords and hyphenated phrases

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, sphinx

Running into an odd issue with Sphinx and stopwords in hyphenated phrases. I have a large number of Sphinx indexes running backend search for articles. Among the properties indexed is the article's URL slug. I'm using inflex searching for the slugs to make it easier for users to find older items.

Here's the problem, given a slug like this:

```
an-optional-text-string
```

A user searching for the full text receives no results. But if you drop the "an-" and just use "optional-text-string" or just "optional-text" or "text-string", the document returns as expected.

I'm thinking it may be a stopword issue? That perhaps Sphinx indexer is removing the "an-" bit but the search query parser isn't?

Has anyone else run into this?

This is the simplified version of my source and index config

```
source articleSource
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = 
    sql_user        = 
    sql_pass        = 
    sql_db          = 

    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre = DELETE FROM foundry_registry where name='__index_articles'
    sql_query_pre = INSERT INTO foundry_registry (SELECT (SELECT MAX(uid)+1 from foundry_registry), '__index_articles', MAX(modified), 0, '__core' FROM gryphon_articles)

    sql_query       = \
        select a.uid as id, a.uid as item_id, a.headline as title, a.abstract as description, a.copy, \
            a.created, a.published, a.modified, a.status, 'article' as type, a.slug as url_slug, \
            group_concat(t.name) as tags, \
            group_concat(au.name) as authors, \
            a.workflow_id, a.section_id, a.issue_id, '0' as blog_id \
            from gryphon_articles as a \
            left join gryphon_articlesTags as at on at.article_id = a.uid \
            left join gryphon_tags as t on at.tag_id = t.uid \
            left join gryphon_articlesAuthors as aa on aa.article_id = a.uid \
            left join gryphon_authors as au on aa.author_id = au.uid \
            group by a.uid


    sql_attr_multi          = uint tag from query; SELECT article_id, tag_id as tag from gryphon_articlesTags
    sql_attr_multi          = uint author from query; SELECT article_id, author_id as author from gryphon_articlesAuthors

    sql_field_string = title
    sql_field_string = description
    sql_field_string = copy
    sql_field_string = type
    sql_field_string = url_slug
    sql_field_string = tags
    sql_field_string = authors
    sql_field_string = workflow_id
    sql_field_string = section_id
    sql_field_string = issue_id

    sql_attr_uint = item_id
    sql_attr_uint = created
    sql_attr_uint = published
    sql_attr_uint = modified
    sql_attr_uint = blog_id

    sql_attr_bool = status

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM gryphon_articles WHERE uid=$id

}

index articleIndex
{
    source          = articleSource

    path            = /path/to/index

    docinfo         = extern

    mlock           = 0

    morphology      = stem_en

    min_word_len        = 1

    charset_type        = utf-8

    enable_star     = 1

    html_strip      = 0
    html_remove_elements    = style, script

    min_infix_len   = 3
    infix_fields    = url_slug
}
```

Comment: There are no 'automatic' stopwords. Only if you explicitly configure them with stopwords. But there are all sort of other issues it could be. What is your exact "index" config.

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter, I just added it.